# files downloaded via expressjs are all corrupted

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, download, upload

When I try to download a file from my Nodejs server using expressjs's res.download() all the file-types I try result in a corrupted file. my downloaded files are all as big as the uploaded ones, and PDF's for example have the exact same amount of pages, just empty.
Uploading files seems to be working correctly.

I am probably overlooking something but I cannot figure out what.

React 'getFile'

```js
const getFile = () => {
  API.instance.get(`${downloadUrl}/download/${file.name}`)
      .then((result) => {
          fileDownload(result.data, file.name)
      }
}
```

Nodejs 'downloadFile'

```js
exports.downloadFile = async (req, res) => {
  const file = `./files/organisations/${req.params.organisationId}/${req.params.filename}`
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept')
  res.download(file);
}
```

React 'uploadFile

```js
const uploadFile = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append('file', selectedFile)
    API.instance.post(`/organisations/${organisationId}/upload`, formdata, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
    }).then(result => {
        // Do stuff
    })
}
```

Nodejs 'uploadFile'

```js
exports.uploadFile = async (req, res) => {
  let file = null
  if (req.files) {
    file = req.files.file

    // ...
    // Create folder
    // ...

    await file.mv(`./files/organisations/${req.params.organisationId}/${file.name}`)

    try {
      await OrganisationModel.addFile(req.params.organisationId, file.name, req.body.userId)
      res.status(200).send(req.params.organisationId)
    } catch(err) {
      res.status(500).send(err)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are downloading a blob file and you need to convert it to a real file using this code:

```
const getFile = () => {
  API.instance.get(`${downloadUrl}/download/${file.name}`)
      .then((result) => {
          let blob = new Blob([result.data] , {type: 'application/pdf', })
          var fileUrl = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(blob);
          newWindow.location = fileUrl
      }
}
```

also, you should set `responseType` to `arraybuffer`,

Comment: Just adding ```{responseType: arraybuffer}``` to the get request did it for me!